# Distinct Count of Texts by filtering to PreviousMonth

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to see total number of team members who registered their hours spent on their projects in previous month (June in this case). The `Engmt` table is:

[image: Engmt Table sample]

With the measure I wrote below filters foe June however doesn't distinctly count the names (includes the team member 1 and 4 twice). The output I get is 6, however, is supposed to be 5.

```
currentMonth =
SUMX(
    FILTER(
        'Engmt',DATE (YEAR('Engmt'[Month]), MONTH('Engmt'[Month]), 1)
        = DATE ( YEAR (TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY())-1,1)
    ),
    CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Engmt'[Name])
))
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post

Comment: why dont you use simply the filter with relative date ? 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VcW8MN3moHm9udv_JuB4uCQdyuMqbf90/view?usp=sharing

Comment: When you define the date inside the filter argument, your year reference is not right. Also, It is much faster to use 'DATEADD()'  function to refer to the previous month.

Answer (score 0):

```
CurrentMonth = distinctcount(Engmt[Name])
```

Use the filter with Relative Date...

[Sample File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VcW8MN3moHm9udv_JuB4uCQdyuMqbf90/view?usp=sharing)

[image: Filter]

Answer (score 0):

don't panic ). Lets understand whats going on. you get 6 and it is a unique names qty in all your table. So, your filter doesn't works.

```
currentMonth =    
    SUMX(
        FILTER(
            'Engmt'
             ,DATE(
                  YEAR('Engmt'[Month]) -- how can you get a year from this? 
                                       -- it's hard to say, but it's not possible, sorry.
                  ,MONTH('Engmt'[Month])
                  ,1
              ) = DATE(
                       YEAR (TODAY())
                       ,MONTH(TODAY())-1
                       ,1
                  )
        )
        ,CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Engmt'[Name]))
    )
```

But you are close to get the right result. Ok, you have only month values in your table. Lets use it.

```
currentMonth = 
     CALCULATE(
         DISTINCTCOUNT('Engmt'[Name])
        ,'Engmt'[Month]=FORMAT( 
                               DATE(
                                   YEAR (TODAY())
                                   ,MONTH(TODAY())-1
                                   ,1
                                )
                                ,"MMMM"
                          )
    )
```

It can not work due to different reasons, for example: a space after month name in the table or smthg else. But, most probably it will. Anyhow it's less tricky to use a slicer. It will help to filter the table in proper way, then `DISTINCTCOUNT('Engmt'[Name])` is enough.

Comment: if the answer was usefull then you can mark it as an answer.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I actually changed the sequence of the lines and it worked. But I'm still not convinced. I mean why it doesn't distinct count after filtering but works when counts distinct and then filters.
`currentMonth = SUMX(CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Engmt'[Name]), FILTER( 'Engmt',DATE (YEAR('Engmt'[Month]), MONTH('Engmt'[Month]), 1) = DATE ( YEAR (TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY())-1,1))))`

Also, I'm not sure if this line
`DATE( YEAR (TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())-1,1)`
will work when it's Jan 23 and will show me Dec 22.

Comment: @selin thank you for your feedback. It works only with month names not years.You dont have years in the table. You need to add a year to the table if you want to use it and then the measure should be altered. I checked a workability of the measure with you data set and it was ok.

Comment: regarding your changes i didn't get the point of the problem. Can you add the result to your question field? and let me know with if you will.

Comment: `YEAR('Engmt'[Month])` - this is a non working construction

Comment: `MONTH('Engmt'[Month])` this one is also. MONTH returns a number of month 1-12 from a date not from name or any non date value